# The Development Server Returned Error Code:500(React Native)

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

Hello I am pretty new to react native I am working on this project it is a Sign In/Sign Up page for a project i am working on [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Igg1d.jpg)
Running through expo,
Running this on a physical device.
I have tried other options available on stack overflow none of them at least worked for me

```html
***App.js***
import React from 'react'
import{StyleSheet,Text,View}from 'react-native'
import RegForm from './app/Components/RegForm' 
export default class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <View style={Styles.Container}>
        <RegForm />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
const styles=StyleSheet.Create({
  container:{
    flex:1 ,
    justifyContent:'center',
    backgroundColor:'#36485f' ,
    paddingLeft:60 ,
    paddingRight:60 ,
  },
})
```

This is the code for the registration page of the app

```html
***RegForm***
import React from 'react'
import{StyleSheet,Text,View,TextInput,TouchableOpacity}from 'react-native'

export default class RegForm extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <View style={Styles.RegForm}>
        <Text style={styles.header}>Registration</Text>
        <TextInput style={styles.TextInput} placeholder="Please Enter your Name" />
        <TextInput style={styles.TextInput} placeholder="Please Enter your Email" />
        <TextInput style={styles.TextInput} placeholder="Please Enter your Password"
        secureTextEntry={true} />
        <TextInput style={styles.TextInput} placeholder="Please Enter your Mobile No" />
        <TextInput style={styles.TextInput} placeholder="Please Enter your CNIC" />
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.btntext}>Sign Up</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
const styles=StyleSheet.Create({
  RegForm:{
    alignSelf:'strech' ,
  },
  header:{
fontSize:24 ,
color:'#fff',
paddingBottom:10 ,
marginBottom:40 ,
borderBottomColor:'#199187',
borderBottomWidth:'1',
  },
  TextInput:{
      alignSelf:'strech',
      height:40 ,
      marginBottom:30 ,
      color:'#fff' ,
      borderBottomColor:'#f8f8f8',
      borderBottomWidth:1 ,
  },
  button:{
      alignSelf:'strech',
      alignItem:'center',
      padding:20 ,
      backgroundColor:'#59cbbd',
      marginTop:30 ,
  },
  btntext:{
      color:'#fff',
      fontWeight:'bold',
  }
})
```

Comment: Have to connect both your device and PC to the same network>

Comment: Already connected!

Answer (score 0):

please check you code

```
***App.js***
import React from 'react'
import{StyleSheet,Text,View}from 'react-native'
import RegForm from './app/Components/RegForm' 
export default class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <View style={styles.Container}>
        <RegForm />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
const styles=StyleSheet.Create({
  container:{
    flex:1 ,
    justifyContent:'center',
    backgroundColor:'#36485f' ,
    paddingLeft:60 ,
    paddingRight:60 ,
  },
})
```

you are using 'Styles' instead of 'styles' in

```
 <View style={Styles.RegForm}>
```

Try to remove the node_modules and package-lock.js and clear the npm cache and expo cache and start the application again,

npm cache clean --force

expo start --clear

Comment: I am facing this error when using the command expo start --clear.                               ''Cannot determine which native SDK version your project uses because the module `expo` is not installed.

Comment: it might happen because expo cli is not install,
To install Expo CLI, just run `npm install -g expo-cli`